# Calculate number of elements in a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How many natural numbers are there below 1000 that are multiples of 3 or that contain 3 in any digit of the number?

My effort : Here we need to calculate union of two set. First set is natural number which are multiple of 3. So it's cardinality will be the nearest integer of 1000/3, which will be 333. But I am confused with second set.

Any help/hint in this regards would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: OK, what have you tried?

Comment: You probably want to apply the _inclusion-exclusion principle_ to this problem - in this case, in the form $\left|A\cup B\right| = \left|A\right| + \left|B\right| - \left|A\cap B\right|$.

Comment: Definitely. But my question is how to figure out the second set?

Comment: Nearest integer will not always be correct. For the numbers $1$ to $1001$ you would have $1001/3$ and the nearest integer is $334,$ but still there are only actually $333$ multiples of $3$ in that set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cardinality of the second set can be calculated as the complement of those numbers not containing $3$, thus (since we can choose each digit independently for $10^3=1000$ possibilities) $10^3-9^3=271$.

Those numbers in the intersection of the two sets, those divisible by $3$ and containing it as a digit, may be calculated as the sum of the following disjoint cases:

- *One $3$.* The $3$ may be placed in any one of $3$ positions, and the other two digits must form a number divisible by $3$. There are $33$ such two-digit numbers, but we exclude $03,30,33,36,39,63,93$ for including a $3$ themselves. Hence there are $3×(33-7)=78$ numbers in this case.
- *Two $3$s.* Again, the $3$'s may be placed in $3$ configurations. The remaining digit must be $0,6,9$, so there are $3×3=9$ numbers in this case.
- The only admissible number with three threes is of course $333$.

Thus the intersection contains $78+9+1=88$ numbers. The desired answer is then $333+271-88=516$.

Comment: There aren't $9^3$ three digit numbers that don't contain a 3, there are $8\cdot9\cdot9$ because you need to avoid leading zeroes too.

Comment: @MatthewDaly We are counting _numbers less than $1000$_, not _three-digit numbers_. And the numbers less than $100$ can be considered to have leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

How many numbers have $3$ as a first digit?  How many number that do not have $3$ as a first digit have $3$ as a second?  How many that do not have $3$ in one of the first two positions have $3$ in the third?  Add these together to answer your question.  You can't just add this to $333$ because all the ones that are multiples of $3$ and have a $3$ in them have been counted twice.

Answer (score 0):

Well, inclussion exclusion says the answer will be

(A)#numbers divisible by three + (B)#numbers with at least one three - (C)#numbers divisible by three and at least on three.

(A) is easy.  $\lfloor \frac{1000}3 \rfloor = 333$.

(B) = #total number - #numbers with *not* threes.

If we consider the numbers as three digits from $000$ to $999$ there are $10^3$ where the digits can be anything and $9^3$ where the digits can be anything but $3$.  So $B=  10^3 -9^3 = (10-9)(10^2 + 10*9 + 9^2)= 271$

(C) is the tricky one but if you know the "rule of three" that if $100a + 10b + c$ is a multiple of $3$ then $a+b+c$ is a multiple of $3$.  And if one of $a,b,c$ is $3$ then the other two add to a multiple of $3$.

Those options are $0+3, 1+2, 2+1,3+0, 0+6, 1+5$ etc.  but we have to worry of double counting.

(C) = (D)#with exactly one three and the other two adding to a multiple of three + (E)#with exactly two threes and the third being a muliptle of three + (F)#with exactly three threes.

For (D) the other two numbers can be $(1,2),(2,1),(1,5),(2,4),(4,2),(5,1),(1,8),(2,7),(4,5),(5,4),(7,2),(8,1)$.  That is $12$ options.  ANd there are three options for which digit is the $3$.  So $D = 3*12=36$

For (E) the third digit can be $0,6$ or $9$.  And there are $3$ positions it can be in.  So (E) = $3*3=9$.

And (F) is obviously equal to $1$.

So $C = 36+9 + 1 = 46$.

We have A + B -C= $333 + 271- 46 =558$.